# Cannot click an element , Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

with selenium, i'm trying to click an element but not working with this element,
the page is here [page](http://software.zkteco.co.id:8088/) (username/password :admin/admin)

[image]

```
wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="operate2a5a0448a8bf44a8898ec13e95b152fc"]/div/div[2]')))
element.click()
```

i tried this on other element in the same page and got no problem

no idea why not working on this element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operate2a5a0448a8bf44a8898ec13e95b152fc` seems to be dynamically created id.
The simplest way to access this element is with text based XPath locator:

```
wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Entry Registration')]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with below code as well :

```
//img[contains(@src,'registration')]/..
```

in code :

```
wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src,'registration')]/..")))
element.click()
```